# how can we add a COM Control in WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have added reference to a COM component in my WPF application. But while I'm trying to add that control to toolbox its not getting listed properly. How can I use a COM control in WPF application?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean an ActiveX control, since COM does not have to have a visual aspect.  Here is a link to a walkthrough from Microsoft's MSDN.

[Walkthrough: Hosting an ActiveX Control in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742735.aspx)

Their example being to use the Windows.Forms integration.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
   // Create the interop host control.
   System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost host =
        new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();

   // Create the ActiveX control.
   AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer axWmp = new AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer();

   // Assign the ActiveX control as the host control's child.
   host.Child = axWmp;

   // Add the interop host control to the Grid
   // control's collection of child controls.
   this.grid1.Children.Add(host);

   // Play a .wav file with the ActiveX control.
   axWmp.URL = @"C:\Windows\Media\tada.wav";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is simple to add COM control to WPF using **WindowsFormsHost**.
But, the problem using WindowsFormsHost that it does not allow to set ZIndex, it will always displayed on top of page.